# How to access the list of available boxes in a vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to make my Vagrantfile smarter by switching between two different boxes depending on what's available.

I'd like to be able to create a box from ubuntu/trusty, and configure it with Puppet (already done), but then I'd like to package that box and create further machines using this one as the starting point.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
available_boxes = <your answer here>
if available_boxes.include? 'my/custombox'
    config.vm.box = 'my/custombox'
else
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty'
end
```

This way the first time it'll start from ubuntu/trusty, but after you've provisioned the first vm you can do:

```
vagrant package --base my/custombox
```

or something like that, and from there on this one is taken as the base box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 available_boxes= `vagrant box list`.gsub(/\s+\(.*\)\n/,"\n").split("\n")
```

`vagrant box list` runs a subshell to list the available boxes, `gsub(/\s+\(.*\)\n/,"\n")` processes the output with pattern matching substitution so we get one box name per line, and `.split("\n")` splits the string into an array element for each line of command output.

The regex decomposes as follows: `\s+` (one or more spaces), `\(.*\)` (followed by any characters within parentheses), and `\n` (followed by a newline).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I thought that this would create an evaluation loop. But this worked like a charm. I guess though, that this solution works only on linux-like envs? perhaps the shell evaluation doesn't work well in windows, but I can't test it.  In any case it works great for me (Mac and Linux)

Comment: I am able to run this under windows, but I also have git bash installed. That is a poor assumption on my part.

Seems [it is generally possible](http://codingbee.net/tutorials/ruby/ruby-use-backticks-and-system-to-run-bash-or-powershell-commands/), but there might be some things to work out specifically for Vagrant.